# Use two digits from the same jTextfield to perform a calculation

Tags: java

I have completed a basic calculator as part of the assignment.
I am currently using two text feild to enter the opperands. and then I press the operator to display the answer.

However, both integers are supposed to be entered from the same textfield, so how do I do that?

I have considered using an array or stack, but I could'nt get it to work.

I included my code below... The calculator is ready, and all works well, it does multiplication division addition and subtraction, and displays the answer in a text area, the two numbers to be added or subtracted... are typed into two seperate fields, once pressing the opperand the calculation is done (Reverse Polish Notation), however, how can I eliminate the use of the 2nd field, and just enter the first value into a textfield, press enter then insert the second value into the same text field and pressing enter. Saving the first as valA and second as val B (integers). but it has to be the same textfield.

```
/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */

/*
 * Calcu.java
 *
 * Created on Feb 9, 2011, 10:11:37 PM
 */

/**
 *
 * @author Halaseh
 */
public class Calcu extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /** Creates new form Calcu */
    public Calcu() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /** This method is called from within the constructor to
     * initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
     * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jScrollPane1 = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
        jTextArea1 = new javax.swing.JTextArea();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jTextArea1.setColumns(20);
        jTextArea1.setRows(5);
        jScrollPane1.setViewportView(jTextArea1);

        jTextField1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jTextField2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jTextField2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton1.setText("+");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setText("-");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setText("*");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setText("/");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                    .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                        .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton3)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                        .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, layout.createSequentialGroup()
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                            .addComponent(jButton2))))
                .addContainerGap(222, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jScrollPane1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton1)
                    .addComponent(jButton2))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
                .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3)
                    .addComponent(jButton4))
                .addContainerGap(69, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int valB = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());        // TODO add your handling code here:

        int valC = valA+valB;
        jTextArea1.append(Integer.toString(valC));
        jTextArea1.append("\n");


    }

    private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {

 int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
    }

    private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int valB = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int valB = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());        // TODO add your handling code here:

        int valC = valA-valB;
        jTextArea1.append(Integer.toString(valC));
        jTextArea1.append("\n");        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int valB = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());        // TODO add your handling code here:

        int valC = valA*valB;
        jTextArea1.append(Integer.toString(valC));
        jTextArea1.append("\n");        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
int valA = Integer.parseInt(jTextField1.getText());
int valB = Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());        // TODO add your handling code here:

        int valC = valA/valB;
        jTextArea1.append(Integer.toString(valC));
        jTextArea1.append("\n");        // TODO add your handling code here:
    }

    /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new Calcu().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JScrollPane jScrollPane1;
    private javax.swing.JTextArea jTextArea1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    // End of variables declaration

}
```

Comment: Oh and i forgot to mention, I just started learning Java today, so I think I have done well to do this calculator from scratch, my own code n all. But i might not understand how to do things alone, so examples might be helpful, thanks a million!

Answer (score 2):

You will have to read in the input and parse the string in some way.

If you only have to expect things of the form 1+3, or 4*5, etc, you can check the operation by asking whether there exists any of the operator symbols

```
if(inputString.indexOf("+") >= 0) { 
    //handle addition
}
```

And then you could get both of the numbers using:

```
String[] numbers = inputString.split("+");
Integer numberOne = Integer.parseInt(numbers[0]);
...
```

This makes a lot of assumptions, and in general you should check for potential problems, but this just depends on how the project is specified.

Comment: thanks for the reply, two questions.. what does the .split do?
and i already have buttons for the opperands. so how exactly would i only save two values?
im thinking maybe 
string [] array;
int valA = Integer.parseInt(array[0]);
int valB = Integer.parseInt(array[1]);

I know the syntax is wrong

Comment: You would only store a first and a second value, like you have written.  .split(...) will split up a value by the string you pass it, so "3+4+5".split("+") would return like [3,4,5].  You should learn to love API documentation when trying to figure out what methods do: String's a good place to start: http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/index.html?java/lang/String.html

Answer (score 0):

Either include a submit button or listen for the enter key to be pressed, and have the program read the number from the text field and store it in a variable.  Then you could display the entered number somewhere else?

Not entirely sure what your assignment requires, but I would consider just having the user enter the entire equation ("1 + 2") and then parsing it.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing the whole string after it is entered would be best, in case the user changes their mind. Try converting it to a char array and then looking for single or consecutive numbers and operands.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, I cannot yet comment..

But to listen for the enter key in a jTextField, use this code:

```
EntryBox.addKeyListener(
            new KeyAdapter() {

                public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
                    int key = e.getKeyCode();
                    if (key == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
                        ActionToPerform(null);
                    }
                }
            });
```

EntryBox is my jTextField, and ActionToPerform is a method that is called when the Enter Key is hit.  In ActionToPerform, you would copy the text/number from EntryBox into a variable.  Also, I would suggest ending ActionToPerform with

```
EntryBox.setText("");
```

This clears the text box, so it's ready to accept another number.